# How to start a different activity with some delay after pressing a button in android?

Tags: android

I want that a new activity should start with some delay on pressing a button.
Is it possible to do that , and whats the procedure.

Comment: Mind if I ask why you felt you needed the delay? I noticed this written in an old project for work, I'm not sure why they chose to do this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could call a Runnable using the Handler postDelayed() method.

Here's an example (http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html):

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

...

OnClickListener mStartListener = new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
   }
};

private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
       // do what you need to do here after the delay
   }
};
```

Props to @mad for getting it right the first time around.

Answer (score 33):

Use a postDelayed() call with a runnable that launches your activity.
An example code could be

```
    //will care for all posts
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    //the button's onclick method
    onClick(...)
    {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask,MYDELAYTIME);
    }

    //will launch the activity
    private Runnable mLaunchTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MYACTIVITY.CLASS);
            startActivity(i);
        }
     };
```

Note that this lets the interface remain reactive. You should then care for removing the onclick listener from your button.

Answer (score 17):

Use This code

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            LaunchActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            LaunchActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }, 4000);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the method `postDelayed(Runnable action, long delayMillis)` of a `View` to add a `Runnable` to the message queue to be run after an (approximate) delay.

Comment: This will allow for your desired behaviour without blocking the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, u need to do it whenever your app process is killed or not. In that case you can not use handling runnable or messages inside your process. In this case your can just use AlarmManager to this. Hope this example helps anybody:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
...

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(<your context>, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, <your delay>, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }, 4000);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this piece of code

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
    @Override
    public void run() {

        // run AsyncTask here.    


    }
 }, 3000);
```