# Wait 1 second inside a listener?

Tags: android, multithreading, wait

How can i do this ? 
I tryed with some thread but nothing happened.

```
        myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) 
            {
                myButton.setClickable(false);

                //Here i want to wait 1 second then:

                myButton.setClickable(true);

                return false;
            }

        });
```

Can anybody implement the one second waiting inside my code please ?

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958628/how-to-start-a-different-activity-with-some-delay-after-pressing-a-button-in-and

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you would wait there you will block the UI thread. Your users will hate you for that. If you describe more in detail what you want to accomplish we might be able to help you with a better solution.

A better solution is to use the postDelayed method

```
    myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) 
        {
            myButton.setClickable(false);

            //wait 1 second
            myButton.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    myButton.setClickable(true);                        
                }
            }, 1000);


            return false;
        }

    });
```

Comment: I assume that you have been downvoted twice because you gave this as an answer to the OP, which it is not, (even though waiting in a GUI event handler is a really lame design, as you say).

Comment: yeah. i hope that the op is not going to use the top voted answer but a solution which does not block the ui.

Answer (score 7):

You definitely don't need to block UI thread by calling **Thread.sleep(1000)**, So you need to achieve it through Handler which runs the desired operation after 1 second on UI thread:

```
//initialize it in your activity so that the handler is bound to UI thread
Handler handlerUI = new Handler();

myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) 
            {
                myButton.setClickable(false);

                //Here i want to wait 1 second then:

                handlerUI.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      myButton.setClickable(true);
                    }
                }, 1000);

                return false;
            }

        });
```

Comment: I just had to initalize the handlerUI but works very well, thank you.

Comment: yup, thats a standard way to do it. DONT use *Thread.Sleep* (mentioned in other answers) as it will hang/block your UI thread for 1 second

Answer (score 1):

you can use a `CountDownTimer` with one second like this :

```
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) 
            {
                myButton.setClickable(false);

                //Here i want to wait 1 second then:
                new CountDownTimer(1000,1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long arg0) {}

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                myButton.setClickable(true);
            }
        }.start();
                return false;
            }
```

**NB :** if you used the `Thread.sleep(int miliseconds ) ;` your UI will be blocked for a while

Answer (score 0):

```
    final  CountDownTimer gps_timer;
    isLocationAvailable=false;
    m_forsms=forsms;

    locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0f, this);
        else
    {
        sendLocation_network(forsms);
        return;
    }

    gps_timer  = new CountDownTimer(15000,1000) {

      int nn=0;
        @Override
        public void onTick(long arg0) {
            nn++;
            Toast.makeText(context, "gps counter :" + nn, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (isLocationAvailable) {
                locationManager.removeUpdates(SendSMS.this);
                gps_h.sendEmptyMessage(0);

            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if (isLocationAvailable) {
                locationManager.removeUpdates(SendSMS.this);
                //Toast.makeText(context, "gps finish ok :" + nn, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                //Toast.makeText(context, "GPS Fail  :" + nn, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                sendLocation_network(m_forsms);

            }
        }
    };

      gps_h=new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
            gps_timer.cancel();
            return true;
        }
    });

    gps_timer.start();
```

Comment: you can use hadler for cancel counter

Answer (score -1):

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

or

```
Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
```

Comment: Another user has already suggested this solution. Unfortunately, it appears to interfere with the UI's sleep thread, which detracts drastically from usability.

Answer (score -3):

`getThread().sleep(1000)` with a proper `try catch` block.

Comment: (1) `getThread()` is not necessary, and not at all recommended.  `Thread.sleep` is static, and if you get used to calling it on a Thread object, you may get the (mistaken) impression it causes the thread you call it on to sleep -- when in reality it always pauses the *current* thread.  (2) `sleep(...)` is *almost always* the wrong answer.  In this case, since it's running on the UI thread, it'll freeze the UI while it waits.  Far better would be to do this asynchronously if at all possible (which, as evidenced by the other answers, it is).